# Library failed to load 'dll' in LabVIEW

Tags: labview

I want to use this project [face_eye_detection.zip](https://forums.ni.com/t5/kl3m3n-s-blog/Real-time-face-and-eye-detection-in-LabView-using-OpenCV-Harr/ba-p/3486952).

When I run it I get an error 'library failed to load'[image],

So I changed the dll link [image]
but the problem remains the same, I even change the dll link and it doesn't work.
Where exactly is the problem? In the link above, the program worked well with the others

Comment: I guess dll's dependencies are missing. Do you have dlls for OpenCV?

Comment: @kosist I downloaded opencv, I have the dll of the project "face_detection_haar_DLL.dll"

Comment: You should be able to see the dependencies for the DLL you have downloaded using this software https://github.com/lucasg/Dependencies

Answer (score 0):

Double check that it is a c++ dll and not a dotnet dll, that one has got me before.